# C# Web Service client that will fail if WSDL is not available or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl, asmx

My client hosts a few web services and has ASP.NET Web pages that will demo the web service and acts as a quick check to verify that the web service is up by the client.  The problem is that the WSDL might be missing or invalid, but the Web Service will still work.

What I'd like to add to the ASP.NET web service client is a way to verify that the WSDL is there and valid, but have no idea where to start.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Code behind is C#

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entiery sure what you mean with verify that the WSDL is valid. Only thing I can suggest is, use an `HttpWebRequest` on the specific URI and see what response you get then either throw an exception based on specific status codes like 404 for example or handle it in a different way.

You can fetch the status code value

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/service.wsdl");
using (var r = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    var result = r.StatusCode.ToString() == 200.ToString() ? "Success" : "Service not found";
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Hope this helps, goodluck.

**Edit:** if you know what services you're going to be testing you can simply add them as service reference in your client project and try to do an RPC on the service methods to see if it's available. Pictures below show to add a service reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll try this out when I start work on Monday, but I think this combination will help me verify that the correct WSDL is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario doesn't completely make sense. You could make a request to the service WSDL endpoint, `http://something/service.asmx?wsdl` and you could confirm that what comes back is a WSDL file. You could even validate it against the WSDL and XSD schemas.

This wouldn't tell you whether it was a WSDL that represented the service. It could conceivably be a WSDL for some totally different service.

Maybe more importantly, have you had problems where the service was available but the WSDL was not? In that case, rather than create diagnostics, I recommend that you fix the problem.

Comment: The service was available, but the WSDL was not available.  Once we realized that the WSDL was restored and everyone could use it going forward.  We are now worried that the service will once again be available, but the WSDL won't, hence the question.